# Products uploaded into Magento via Magmi not updating frontend after updated from admin area

Tags: attributes, frontend, magmi, image-upload

In a bit of a pickle with recent Magento project. Uploaded a few hundred products via Magmi, uploaded into the admin area fine. I updated 1 of the products manually from the admin area. It updates fine in the admin area, but the changes for certain attributes/values don't show in the frontend! So for example the name, url and images won't update. They change and show fine in the admin area. I can update any other attribute fine. E.g. size or colour. They update into the frontend fine. Prices are updating fine too. It's just the name, url and images that are not changing in the frontend. So the fact some attributes are updating rules our cache? Although I checked that anyway. And the fact that some attributes are updating rules out permissions issue on server or the like?

If I upload a product from scratch via the Magento admin panel, and change the name, images or url, it updates fine!! It's just products uploaded via Magmi that aren't updating.......

Uploaded in Magmi and checked the Magmi Optimizer and Image attributes processor options only. Never experienced this issue before using Magento or Magmi in the last 3 years or so. Very confused on here..... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The feeling I'm getting from the problem here is that I've uploaded them initially from Magmi incorrectly somehow, so am going to try changing options there and see if I can get some joy.

Comment: Ok, update of sorts.... my problem only affects some uploads from Magmi, not all. I guess the obvious fix is delete all products affected and re-upload them from scratch, but would be good to find out what the issue was!! It will probably be something selected wrong in Magmi on initial upload causing the products to go into the Magento system incorrectly, not sure what or why though......

Comment: I'll delete this entire question if I can't find anything constructive as an answer to put in or if it won't be of any use to anyone else etc.....

Comment: Sounds like Index and/or Cache issue. Which modes have your indexes? Have you rebuilt them after the change? Have you cleared the cache afterwards? Do you use Flat Catalog or not?

Comment: Yeah, checked cache and index thoroughly prior to posting this question to rule them out. I have use flat catalog product set to yes. I deleted the problem products, re-uploaded them from scratch via Magmi with same settings as detailed above, and working fine now..... very strange.... I must have had something different in Magmi though on initial upload to cause.

Comment: hm... strange indeed. You post and self-accept your answer. :)

Comment: The only other thing I could attribute the problem too would be php settings on server which I changed this morning, which would be the only thing changed between the 2 uploads. So initially uploaded with Apache for php hosting, and now set at FastCGI scripting, but can't see how that would be connected at all......

Comment: Hm. Problems that leave without change come back without change :D let's hope for the best

Answer (score 1):

This is more than likely due to the indexing process not having run.  When you save a product in the backend of Magento, you are likely pushing the new data into the index (default option is index on save).

You should run a full re-index after importing products and changes via magmi.  If you have a significant number of products, I would recommend that you SSH in and run

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: system > config > catalog > SEO > Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed > set this to "no"